# excel macro copy range to a specified sheet and then loop the next range

Tags: excel, macros, vba

I found many useful codes for my project but now I'm a bit stuck, because of my very poor coding knowledge, if you can help I would be very glad to it. Thanks in advance.

So my problem is that i have to create a loop that runs x times (it varies because the ranges are rounds of soccer leagues). what the code has to do, that copies cells of sheet2 (A2:I13) to sheet1 (B2) and later it jumps to (A14:I25) and so on. The range always 12 lines and 9 columns (or A:I). It has to do till first A cell is empty (this is the end).

I don't think its a difficult problem, but i don't know how to search the 13th cell. thanks for your help

Comment: Can you please share the code you have tried so far. What part of your code is working and what is not working

Comment: YowE3K has answered my question but thank you, too

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a For / Next loop such as:

```
For rowNumber = 2 to lastRow Step 12
    ' do whatever needs to be done
    ' ...
Next
```

Or you could just use a counter and a Do While Loop such as:

```
rowNumber = 2
Do While Cells(rowNumber, 1).Value <> ""
    ' do whatever needs to be done
    ' ...
    rowNumber = rowNumber + 12
Loop
```